# SSIS has validation error on SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, oledb

I'm trying to call a custom stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 from SSIS in Visual Studio 2012. I wrote and tested the stored procedure in SSMS 2012 and it works as expected.

However, when I try to place it in an OLE DB Command component I receive a Divide by 0 error when I refresh the component or when the SSIS package validates.

Here's the code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ldg].[2015HRUpdate(TEST)]
    @Employee varchar(20),                      -- maps to EM.Employee, primary key
    @Title varchar(50),                         -- maps to EM.Title
    @PayRate varchar(50) = '0',              -- maps to EM.JobCostRate, convert to decimal
    --  @Percentage Decimal(19,4) = 0,            -- workaround
    @OldPayRate Decimal(19,4) = 0,           -- used to calculate Employees_SalaryHistory.Custnprcent, convert to decimal
    @LaborCategory varchar(50) = '0',           -- maps to EM.BillingCategory, convert to small int
    @EmployeeDesignation varchar(50),           -- maps to EmployeeCustomTabFields.CustEmployeeDesg
    @FSLAStatus varchar(50),                    -- maps to EmployeeCustomTabFields.CustFSLAStatus
    @Supervisor varchar(20),                    -- maps to EM.Supervisor
    @SupervisorName varchar(255),               -- maps to Employees_SalaryHistory.custSuper
    @ModUser nvarchar(20),
    @ModDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Convert data types to match database data types
    declare @JobCostRate decimal(19,4);
    declare @OldJobCostRate decimal(19,4);
    declare @BillingCategory smallint;
    declare @Percent decimal(19,4);

    if @PayRate is null or @PayRate = '' 
      set @PayRate = '0';


    set @JobCostRate = CONVERT(decimal(19,4), @PayRate); 
    set @OldJobCostRate = @OldPayRate;

    /* this works in T-SQL but when SSIS tries to validate I get a div/0 error */
    if @OldJobCostRate != 0
    begin 
      set @Percent = ((@JobCostRate - @OldJobCostRate)/@OldJobCostRate) * 100;  --errors out right here with a divide by 0 error.
      --set @Percent = 0;
    end 
    else
    begin
      set @Percent = 0;
    end

    set @BillingCategory = CONVERT(smallint, @LaborCategory);

    -- SQL statements for procedure here    
      -- Update EM table
    -- Update EmployeeCustomTabFields table
    -- Insert into Salary history table
END
GO
```

I have placed a comment on the line that produces the error.  If I comment that line out and uncomment the one below it SSIS will validate the procedure without issue.

I finally worked around the issue by creating a derived field in the ETL but I would like to know why SSIS/OLE-DB is causing this issue for the next time it pops up.

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 1):

If you alter your procedure to look like

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- This is a bloody hack to get SSIS to be happy about metadata. 
IF 1=2
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS StupidHackery;
END
```

I believe you'll get around this issue. The root cause is that SSIS wants to validate the metadata from the proc and doesn't actually evaluate the logic in there. I don't have any definitive resources on the matter, pity, but for me at least, I could recreate your issue and by using this stupid hack, get around it. I've had to use the same thing when dealing with temporary tables.